# In Spark, how to check the date format?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

How can we check the date format in below code.

```
DF = DF.withColumn("DATE", to_date(trim(col("DATE")), "yyyyMMdd"))
```

**Error:**

> Caused by:  java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2171121' could not be parsed at index 6

**Expectation:**
If the format is correct use the same data otherwise populate null in the same column.

Comment: That format isn't correct, though. year=2171, month=12, day=? You have two `d` for the day, not one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spark 3.1, `from_unixtime`, `unix_timestamp`,`to_unix_timestamp`, `to_timestamp` and `to_date` will fail if the specified datetime pattern is invalid. In Spark 3.0 or earlier, they result NULL. Check documentaion [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html).

To switch back to previous behavior you can use below configuration.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
```

Read what has been changed from spark 3.0 w.r.t datetime parser [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).

You can use when() and otherwise() functions to get desired result, after using above configuration.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(20210822,),(1234,)]).toDF("date")
# casting column to string as to_date function will accept string or date or timestamp type columns
>>> df.withColumn("date", when(to_date(df["date"].cast("string"),"yyyyMMdd").isNull(), None).otherwise(df["date"])).show()
+--------+
|    date|
+--------+
|20210822|
|    null|
+--------+
```